# Add premade Popup Function Form to On Click JS Event

Tags: javascript

I am using unbounce landing page and I want to have paperforms pop up function occur when an element is clicked.

I am new to this so bare with me.

I understand that:

```
$('#my-element-id').click(function() {
   Paperform.popup('my-form-name');
});
```

is for when something is clicked.

Paper form provides:

```html
<button data-paperform-id="quoteclosing" data-popup-button="1">
  Click me to show the form!
</button>
<script>
(function() { 
  var script = document.createElement('script'); 
  script.src = "https://paperform.co/__embed.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(script); 
})()
</script>
```

I dont want to use the premade button in the html they provide. I like the unbounce elements.

Please let me know how I can combine the popup function into the java on click event for an element if given its ID.

Paperform says to use these two things when making your own code:

Just add the attributes data-paperform-id=“my-form-name”and data-popup-button=“1”to make any element show your form when it is clicked.

Thank you